# Why is it not working? it's showing a error before else

Tags: postgresql

this is the code:

```
    -- create
    CREATE TABLE I_UsrAccessRvw (
      empId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      username TEXT NOT NULL,
      designation TEXT NOT NULL,
      roles TEXT NOT NULL,
      accesses TEXT NOT NULL
    );
    
    -- insert
    INSERT INTO I_UsrAccessRvw VALUES (0001, 'Clark','President', 'admin','edit delete review');
    INSERT INTO I_UsrAccessRvw VALUES (0002, 'Dave','sales rep', 'Operational role','review');
    INSERT INTO I_UsrAccessRvw VALUES (0003, 'Ava','finance manager', 'Managerial role','edit delete review');
    
    -- fetch 
    SELECT * FROM I_UsrAccessRvw;
    
    --mastertable
    CREATE TABLE CONDITION (
      roles TEXT NOT NULL,
      accesses TEXT NOT NULL,
      permission TEXT NOT NULL
    );
    
    --insertintomastertable
    INSERT INTO CONDITION VALUES ('admin','edit delete review','granted');
    INSERT INTO CONDITION VALUES ('Managerial role','edit review','granted');
    INSERT INTO CONDITION VALUES ('Operational role','review','granted');
    SELECT * FROM CONDITION;
    
    ALTER TABLE I_UsrAccessRvw
    ADD COLUMN permission TEXT;
    
    UPDATE 
      I_UsrAccessRvw p
      
    SET 
        permission = c.permission
    FROM 
        I_UsrAccessRvw e, CONDITION c
    WHERE 
       e.roles=c.roles and e.accesses= c.accesses and p.empId=e.empid;
    
    ELSE
    SET 
        permission AS "REVOKE"
       
      
       SELECT * FROM I_UsrAccessRvw order by empid;
```

Comment: Table- and column-names are changed to lowercase unless singe-quote is used. That might be the issue here. You can help your future self by using lowercase and underscore (_).

Comment: ELSE is not valid SQL on it's own, something is missing before this. We don't know what your intentions were.

Comment: Actually the code should give anything as a revoke permission which is not granted in the condition table.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `else` condition in SQL (with exception of `case` expression). What you can do is create an assignment CTE using a `left outer join`. Then update with the main query.  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=76debf1dfc83903c86008790c5f5bc5a))

```
with permission_set( rctid, permission) as 
     ( select p.ctid, coalesce(c.permission, 'REVOKE')
         from i_usraccessrvw p
         left join condition c 
                on ( (c.roles,c.accesses) = (p.roles,p.accesses) ) 
     )
update i_usraccessrvw i  
   set permission = (select permission 
                       from permission_set ps
                      where i.ctid = ps.rctid
                    );
```

NOTE: You need to learn the new modern join syntax (only 30 years old). The structure used `from I_UsrAccessRvw e, CONDITION c where ...`  is an inner join. If the `where` clause does not match for every row the unmatched rows are simply not processed.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO I_UsrAccessRvw VALUES (0001, 'Clark','President', 'admin','edit delete review');
INSERT INTO I_UsrAccessRvw VALUES (0002, 'Dave','sales rep', 'Operational role','review');
INSERT INTO I_UsrAccessRvw VALUES (0003, 'Ava','finance manager', 'Managerial role','edit delete review');

-- fetch 
SELECT * FROM I_UsrAccessRvw;

--mastertable
CREATE TABLE CONDITION (
                           roles TEXT NOT NULL,
                           accesses TEXT NOT NULL,
                           permission TEXT NOT NULL
);

--insertintomastertable
INSERT INTO CONDITION VALUES ('admin','edit delete review','granted');
INSERT INTO CONDITION VALUES ('Managerial role','edit review','granted');
INSERT INTO CONDITION VALUES ('Operational role','review','granted');
SELECT * FROM CONDITION;

ALTER TABLE I_UsrAccessRvw
    ADD COLUMN permission TEXT;

UPDATE
    I_UsrAccessRvw p

SET
    permission = coalesce(c.permission,'REVOKE')
FROM
    I_UsrAccessRvw e, CONDITION c
WHERE
        e.roles=c.roles and e.accesses= c.accesses and p.empId=e.empid

SELECT * FROM I_UsrAccessRvw order by empid;
```

i think this is what u want to do, else keyword is not used like that.

Comment: Your code is correct but instead of giving the permission as revoke it leaves it as blank

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).